# Rust "borrowed data escapes outside of closure" when temporarily borrowing closure-owned data

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e37c3ec7f31e332189df23485e513e43) is a playground of the issue. The code here is doing something in a very roundabout way but it's the smallest recreation of the issue that still somewhat resembles my actual program--I know it can be easily modified to work and achieve the same thing.

Question: What does this error mean in this context and why is this not allowed?

It seems like "a" is owned by the closure and a.make_borrower() creates a temporary struct that borrows "a" mutably. Then, this struct is dropped before the closure ends. There must be something going wrong with the lifetimes here but I maybe don't have a deep enough understanding of how lifetimes work to see it.

Code pasted here for ease of reading:

```
use core::marker::PhantomData;


struct A<B> {
    borrower_type: PhantomData<B>,
    something: Vec<i32>,
}

impl<'a, B: ABorrower<'a>> A<B> {
    pub fn make_borrower(&'a mut self) -> B {
        B::new(self)
    } 
}

trait ABorrower<'a>: Sized {
    fn new(a: &'a mut A<Self>) -> Self;
    fn borrow(&mut self) -> &mut A<Self>;
}


struct SomeABorrower<'a> {
    a_ref: &'a mut A<Self>,
}
impl<'a> ABorrower<'a> for SomeABorrower<'a> {
    fn new(a: &'a mut A<Self>) -> Self { Self { a_ref: a } }
    fn borrow(&mut self) -> &mut A<Self> { self.a_ref }
}


fn main() {
    let mut a = A::<SomeABorrower> {
        borrower_type: PhantomData,
        something: vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    };
    
    let mut closure = move || {
        a.something[1] += 2;
        {
            let a_borrower = a.make_borrower();
            a_borrower.a_ref.something[1] += 5;
        }
        a.something[1] -= 2;
    };
    
    for _ in 0..100 {
        closure();
    }
}
```

Comment: Having the same lifetime in two places in the same type (one for a mutable reference): like the type of `a` is `&'a mut A<SomeBorrower<'a>>` is almost always wrong, unless you really want to tie your lifetimes in a knot. I think you'll need GATs (generic associated types) to properly express this "borrower", but its a bit hard to understand if that's truly what you want/need since the abstract type names aren't very insightful.

Comment: @kmdreko thanks, I was trying to understand specifically what causes the error here, I understand that this is probably bad design. Didn't think about the fact that the lifetime shows up twice in the same type though, I guess that could help guide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out why it errors:

In my example, initializing A::<SomeABorrower> {...} at the very start sets the lifetime 'a of SomeABorrower<'a> to the outer scope. So when I create a SomeABorrower by doing a.borrow(), it sees the created reference as valid all the way to the scope outside the closure, making a reference that could potentially be used outside the closure to something owned in the closure (hence "escaping" the closure).